# How should "a $5 item" be read?

Tags: grammatical-number

Taken from [this article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hfma.png) (image):

> ...indulge in a **$5 coffee**...

How should I read this? Is it a *five dollars coffee* or a *five dollar coffee*?

Comment: I have removed the article and added an excerpt from it; I have also clarified your question a little bit, and improved the title. Let me know if I missed the meaning of your question at all.

Comment: @Mahnax That was a good edit, I added the link to the image so it won't bother here but it's still available.

Comment: @Alenanno Alright, fair enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be read as *a five dollar coffee*. One would say *a coffee worth five dollars*, but since *five dollar* is an adjective, the singular form of the noun "dollar" should be used.

Comment: this is dissappointed thing to see my question turned a simple one. I have spended a good time to make it but now someone has come and made it a junk... I dont like this situation.

Comment: @Socarsky I am sorry if I have offended you; however, my edits have made the question shorter, clearer, and better, in my opinion, without changing what you're asking. The article was large, and entirely irrelevant, considering you were asking about one little sentence, so I removed it, and put the line that you are asking about into the question. I then clarified the last bit of your question by using proper English, as well as removing a sentence that was made unnecessary by removing the article. What about my edits do you find incorrect?

Comment: @Mahnax That's ok even if I don't want to accept this situation. I should forget this anyway. Thanks

Comment: That was possibly one of the best edits I've seen in a while. I wish I could +1 edits, but I'll +1 your answer instead.